# Bootstrap not loading in pug files

Tags: javascript, express, pug

The Index file in my project extends the layout file and loads the bootstrap framework specified in my pug layout file for styling, but the other pages created do not load any bootstrap? Please can someone explain why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.  We need to see your code in order to help diagnose this problem, preferably with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)